# Create a Model Class Name from a String

Tags: c#, class, activator

I am trying to dynamically insert an existing model class name into a declaration so I don't have to do this:

```
var n1 = entry.Entity as MyClassName1;
var n2 = entry.Entity as MyClassName2; 
var n3 = entry.Entity as MyClassName3; 
[n4...n200]
```

**This is what I am trying to achieve but with the class name generated dynamically**

```
 var n = entry.Entity as MyClassName1;
```

**Here is how I am trying to get there, based on what I read about Activator.CreateInstance.**

```
 //Get string representation of the class name
 var tableNameStr = entry.EntitySet.Name.TrimEnd('s');
 //Get class type
 var t = Type.GetType(tableNameStr);
 //Instantiate
 var n = entry.Entity as (Activator.CreateInstance(t));
```

**Getting the following error:**

```
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an instance of the XY problem. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve by doing this? This smells bad.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  `Entity` already has a type and the underlying type of `var` will already match the correct type.

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance(t)` will create a new instance of an object of type t.  That's an object, not a type, which is (one reason) why you can't use it on the RHS of `as`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends on what you want to do.**

```
var n1 = entry.Entity as MyClassName1;
```

basically does two things:

1. `MyClassName1 n1;` -- it statically types `n1` as `MyClassName1`.
2. `n1 = (entry.Entity is MyClassName1 ? (MyClassName1)entry.Entity : null);` -- it assigns `null` to `n1`, if it is not of type `MyClassName1`¹.

---

**The first thing cannot be done dynamically.** A static type is known *at compile time*.

**The second thing can be done dynamically**:

```
if (GetType(typeNameAsString).IsAssignableFrom(entry.Entity.GetType()) {
    n1 = entry.Entity;
} else {
    n1 = null;
}
```

---

¹ ...with a few exceptions, which are probably irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Activator.CreateInstance is not a type. If you have an Entity class somewhere, you can cast your Instance like this:

```
var n = (Entity)(Activator.CreateInstance(t));
```